# Django translation check without running the project

Tags: django

Is there a simple way to check the correctness of translations in `django.po` file? (I don't mean to check it in the running project)

Answer (score 1):

yes try these commands:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l <your-language-code>
```

and then

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

If everything is okay, no error will happen in your terminal.

Comment: You can aldo use django-rosetta and check translations in admin.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. I just wanted to check if the format of my translation is OK or not.  I knew about finding errors with this way.